# Building a C++ project in Visual Studio doesn't create any files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build

I recently decided to start learning Visual Studio so that it replaces my need for CodeBlocks and MinGW for C++ programming. 
So, today I made a new Win32 C++ Console Application, wrote down this code in a new .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it. The log said

> 1>------ Build started: Project: CPP_CONSOLE_TEST, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(357,5): warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Output Directory.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

and I though my code was compiled and my .exe was created.
Then, upon trying to debug my program, Visual Studio said:

> Unable to start program 'C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CPP_CONSOLE_TEST\Debug\CPP_CONSOLE_TEST.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I then opened the Debug folder of the project and it was completely empty...

I've been searching around Google for some time and I even tried to "Repair" my Visual Studio build with no results. Any help?

Quick edit: Just tried compiling a C# app, just to see if the IDE itself was the problem. It compiled and ran just fine, so it's some issue with the Visual C++ compiler and its settings...

Comment: Quick edit: That Build Log happened after I tinkered around with the Output settings. The original log is this:
1>------ Build started: Project: CPP_CONSOLE_TEST, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
and there are still no files...

Comment: Did you try to re-create the project in a directory with a shorter path, such as C:\Projects\YOUR_PROJECT ?

Comment: Nope, the project directory is in Documents and the Output directory is set to $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\. Everything is in Debug mode, so it should be in the correct place...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I hadn't added the source file to the Project... :|

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio, has its own vision of c++ projects. By default, it needs a `#include "stdafx.h"` on top of your cpp file, with the associated stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp  files.
Then, in a c++ visual studio project, the real definition of the main function is `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`. But it should work with your definition.

Comment: These are all compiler-specific things. The compiler says everything is fine, so I do not think that's the problem...I also just tried out your solutions and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use Serge Rogatch's solution?
There is a bug in Visual Studio which leads to problems when project has long path.

Comment: Oh...I read his solution incorrectly...I'm making the dumbest mistakes today. Anyways, I fixed it, so it doesn't matter anymore.